# Using ImageView in JavaFX controller class

Tags: javafx

I created a javaFX fxml application in NetBeans and want to display an image using a filechooser opened in a handleButtonAction event.

If I drag an ImageView into the panel using the gui builder I see no way to get it's object generated in code.

If I add an Imageview manually to the main class, I do not have the button handler method available, and if I add it to the controller class, I do not have the main panel available to attach the Imageview to. I think I am not understanding how to elements from the ui builder generated into code.

The generated NetBeans projects starts with a hello button that also has no visible object in the source files, so it seems clear that I am missing something about how the ui builder sets the proper xml data to have those elements available to the controller, but there doesn't appear to me to be any way add these to the controller from the ui builder. Is it just that the UI builder is unreliable?

Any help would be appreciated.

The main application class looks like:

```
package javafxapplication2;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class JavaFXApplication2 extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

And the Controller:

```
package javafxapplication2;


import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
//import javafx.scene.image.Image;
//import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
//import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
//import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
//import java.io.File;
//import java.io.IOException;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

 //   private ImageView imgview = new ImageView();
 //   private FileChooser filechooser = new FileChooser();


    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
     //commented out because it displays nothing

//        try {
//            File infile = filechooser.showOpenDialog(null);
//            Image img = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(ImageIO.read(infile), null);
//            imgview.setImage(img);
//        } catch (IOException ex) {
//            Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
//        }
        System.out.println("button clicked");

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

}
```

And the XML:

```
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="355.0" prefWidth="411.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication2.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="312.0" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="open file" />
      <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="84.0" layoutY="73.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
      <Button layoutX="212.0" layoutY="310.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using the ImageView that you have created in the FXML, inside your controller.

You should assign the ImageView a `fx:id` and then inject it in the controller. This way the same ImageView will be used while setting the Image in the ImageView.

**In FXML:**

```
<ImageView fx:id="imgview" fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" 
                  layoutX="84.0" layoutY="73.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
```

**In Controller:**

```
 public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

      @FXML
      private ImageView imgview;
      ...
 }
```

---

### MCVE

**FXML**

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="355.0" prefWidth="411.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="312.0" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="open file" />
        <ImageView fx:id="imageView" fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="84.0" layoutY="73.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
        <Button layoutX="212.0" layoutY="310.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Controller**

```
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ImageView imageView;
    private FileChooser filechooser = new FileChooser();


    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            File infile = filechooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            Image img = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(ImageIO.read(infile), null);
            imageView.setImage(img);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought the fx:id might have been the key, but when I would enter something into the fx:id field nothing would happen. Instead I get this error: "No injectable field found in FMXL controller class for myimgview"

Comment: The value of `fx:id` and the name of the variable annotated with `@FXML` should be same.

Comment: Ok, It actually does seem to be setting the value in the controller menu and shows code in "show sample controller skeleton" Is there a way to get the ui builder to insert this code in the correct place?

Comment: I just have one question, how can I get the builder to insert code into the controller? EDIT: I see that you can right click the fxml and select "make controller" although copy and pasting from the controller code preview is also useful.